# AWS NLB strange situation on cross region access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, transit-gateway

I have connected 2 aws regions with transit gateway.

Region 1 **frankfurt** has **3 private subnets** and **3 public subnets**, the private one has its **route table** with a **Nat interface** and **local subnet route (172.10.0.0/16)**, while the other has the local route and Region 2 **Tokyo** single subnet (**172.20.0.0/16**).

On region 1 i have **EKS** with **3 worker nodes**, which are running on the **3 private subnets**, and its is reachable from the **region1 public subnets**.

I have an nginx (**example.com**) on **EKS** behind an **internal load balancer**, which when i do nslookup resolves in **3 private IPs (which are not the ones, of the 3 workers nodes, on the load balancer target groups)**.From the Region 1 subnet using an EC2 i get response from all 3 IPs of the Load Balancer.

So this is my first question , where can i find where these 3 IP addresses are connected to ? (they look like they are part of the private subnets)

I think Found the answer to the first question (those 3 IPs are the ones of the Classic Load Balancer nodes), one for each AZ. Right ?

​

I added on **Region 1** private subnet route table the subnet IP of the Region 2 subnet (**172.20.0.0/16**), now i can reach the service (nginx example.com) only on 1 of the 3 ips which resolves , on the  2 others i get Connection Time out.

what am i missing ?

thanks a lot

checked security groups of the Nodes in the target groups, of the Classic Load Balancer.

Checked the route tables